# How to add iAd in Cocos-SpriteBuilder

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad, spritebuilder

I am using SpriteBuilder (which integrates with Cocos2d v3.0). I built an app and now I want to put in an iAd at the very top that pops up when I call it, and hides when I tell it to. What's the simplest way to do this?

Keep in mind I am using SpriteBuilder with Cocos2d. And just because I am using SpriteBuilder does not mean I am not using Xcode 5 as well. I am fully involved in Xcode as well. SpriteBuilder does not write the code for me, I do that.

Answer (score 8):

Add iAd framework to your dependencies.

In your header file for your game scene, add the ADBannerViewDelegate, for instance:

```
@interface MainScene : CCNode <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

In your implementation file, add the instance variable _bannerView:

```
@implementation MainScene {
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
}
```

And finally, insert the the iAD code (with some cocos2d tweaks). Here's my implementation for a game in portrait mode with a top banner. There's no hide method, but it's pretty easy to implement.

```
# pragma mark - iAd code

-(id)init
{
    if( (self= [super init]) )
    {
        // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
            _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        } else {
            _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        }
        _adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        _adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
        [_adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
        _adView.delegate = self;
    }
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // As of iOS 6.0, the banner will automatically resize itself based on its width.
    // To support iOS 5.0 however, we continue to set the currentContentSizeIdentifier appropriately.
    CGRect contentFrame = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.bounds;
    if (contentFrame.size.width < contentFrame.size.height) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I thank God for people like you in this world. I've been searching all day onto how to do exactly this and all i found was complex code. Yet when i saw this i was like nahh its too easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you:) I made it into a helper implementation to make the implementation super easy to use:   https://github.com/svenanders/iAdHelper